# Serving Cordova Script files on client side with remote website

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, grails, cordova

I'm currently trying to create a cross-platform app with cordova based on a remote website. So basically all business logic, views etc. are served through a grails project on a remote website. When I try to create the android app with cordova, I'm always stuck where to put the javascript files.

The current Cordova version keeps the scripts (cordova.js, cordova_plugins.js and all plugin files) in the app. I then created a loader html file in the android project (/assets/www/index.html) that loads the cordova js files and then opens my website (mydomain.com/entrypoint).

The problem now is, that the switch to my website results in losing the cordova functionality. On the index page (locally) the js-object navigator is a CordovaNavigator. After loading my website, the js-object is a plain navigator object again. So I can't use the functionality provided by the plugins (like catching the back-button for history modification).

So, to keep the cordova scripts, I already tried to load my website through ajax, but that (of course) results in missing scripts from the head of my website html.

I'm slowly running out of ideas. Providing the script through the server seems like a not-so-nice solution since app version and server version of cordova are then not maintained at the same place.

BTW: I'm using cordova 3.3.0

Any suggestions are highly appreciated

Comment: If you adjust the `content` parameter in your `config.xml` to point directly at your site (instead of using a loader), does that work?

Comment: That does not work either. If i do so, the cordova js files are neither loaded nor referenced in the dom.

Comment: Ok -- try moving the cordova javascript files over to your server so that they can load from the same domain. Not sure if you've perhaps already tried that.

Comment: Thanks for that hint. I already tried that, and it works. But i don't really want to serve the cordova files through my server. For Example: I publish an app with Cordova 3.3.0 and server Cordova 3.3.0 on my server. Now there is a major update and i want to serve Cordova 3.X. I would have to force my users to upgrade the app. And I always have to maintain the version at two different locations - the app and the server.

Comment: I'm running into the same challenges... I want to load the local cordova.js and plugin files locally on the device from a remote site. Were you able to find a solution for this?